# Is there a shortcut syntax to initialize an array with defaults?

Tags: rust

Having this

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Default)]
pub enum CellContent {
    Move(Symbol),
    #[default]
    Empty,
}

pub struct Game {
    pub table: [[CellContent; 3]; 3],
}
```

How can I short this ?

```
pub fn new() -> Game {
    Game {
        table: [
            [
                CellContent::default(),
                CellContent::default(),
                CellContent::default(),
            ],
            [
                CellContent::default(),
                CellContent::default(),
                CellContent::default(),
            ],
            [
                CellContent::default(),
                CellContent::default(),
                CellContent::default(),
            ],
        ],
    }
}
```

| *Please, answering, point me to rust book page* or *other official documentation*

NOTE: I am not looking for some advanced trick, but only to syntax sugar, if any

Comment: Can you `#[derive(Copy, Clone)]` for `CellContent`?

Comment: If needed, I think yes, I am doing small programs to learn by myself rust... what's the goal to derive Copy and Clone in this context? Sorry,... first days on Rust here

Comment: It's a good idea and would make copy-initialization of the arrays possible, but this isn't even required. I will post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the type of an array element implements `Default`, the array type itself does as well, so you can just populate `table` with `Default::default()`:

```
pub fn new() -> Game {
    Game {
        table: Default::default(),
    }
}
```

This will use `Default` to obtain the initial value for the nested arrays, which will in turn use the `Default` implementation of `CellContent` to obtain the initial value for each nested array element.

If your type `CellContent` derives `Copy` then you could also use copy-initialization of array elements; the syntax `[x; N]` creates an array of `N` elements, copying `x` to fill all `N` elements:

```
pub fn new() -> Game {
    Game {
        table: [[CellContent::default(); 3]; 3],
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks !! Is it well documented anywhere?

Comment: Could you kindly add "copy-initialization of the array" ?

Comment: @realtebo Yes. The primitive array type `[T; 3]` [implements `Default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html#impl-Default-25) when `T: Default`.

Comment: @realtebo I've added an example of the copy-initialization approach.

Comment: no, sorry, I mean, where is this syntax _explained_ ?

Comment: @realtebo Which syntax?